# How to add a role profile page to meteor user?

Tags: meteor, roles

I have 2 roles in my app. Users and doctors.
I want that a doctor can edit extra fields like picture and text field on an extra profile page for doctors.

How to add this fields probably not to the profile but to an extra part of the users collection and make it then public availible as a profile page /doctor/_id

I am now experimenting with meteorkitchen, which is great, but when I add a profile.doctor.field1 and show this on an page like user_settings/profile/doctor and update it the other fields of the profile are overwritten with empty values. I assume it assumes that all profile attributes are edited on one form and when one field is empty so it deletes them. But this is not what I want.

(Can someone add a tag meteorkitchen please. I have not enough reputation.  thanks)

**Edit:**
this are the settings for the router

```
var roleMap = [
        ...
    { route: "user_settings.doctor",    roles: ["doctor","admin"] }
];
```

and attached this part for the form

```
"name": "edit_form",
"type": "form",
"mode": "update",
"title": "Edit your doctor profile",
"submit_route": "user_settings.profile.doctor",
"query": {
    "name": "current_user_data",
    "collection": "users",
    "filter": {
       "_id": "Meteor.userId()"
     },
     "find_one": true,
     "options": {},
     "params": []
     },
"fields": [
    {
       "name": "profile.doctor.quote",
       "title": "Favorite quote",
       "type": "string",
       "required": true
   }
]
```

the problem is that on update some of the profile values the others are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with Meteor Kitchen, here is how I would proceed.

- First, you need to create a "doctor" role. See your application page on kitchen designer, you can add it here.
- Second, you need to add your new "doctor" role to the page roles. You can do it directly in the role map located in `client/views/router.js` or using the designer.

**EDIT** Following the discussion in the comments here is an update:

You can change the collection name directly in the section "Edit source" of the designer. You go to your page, in the query, you set

```
"query": {
                "name": "doctor_user",
                "collection": "users",
                "filter": {
                     "_id": ":userId"
                            },
                "find_one": false,
                "options": {},
                "params": []
        },
```

The thing is that even if you do that, only admins can update the users collection. So you need to download the user-roles package from perak, put it inside your project (only put the folders) and remove the user-roles pre-installed package (`meteor remove perak:user-roles`).

Once you have done that, go to `server/collections` and replace the `update` part of `users.js` with that:

```
    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    return Users.isInRole ("admin")||  (Users.isInRole ("doctor") && 
    !_.contains(fieldNames,'roles')));
```

It will allow users with the doctor role to update any user field **except for the "roles" field.**

Last step, you edit the `server\publications\users.js` file and add this in it:

```
Meteor.publish("doctor_user", function(_id){
   return  Users.isInRoles ({"doctor", "admin"}) ? Users.find({_id: _id}) : this.ready();
});
```

Comment: if you want to make "an extra profile page for doctors", it will allow you to set the page accessible only to them using the router. Concerning the data you serve on this page, if you need to protect it, you will have to change the related publish functions. If it is a whole collection, you can make it accessible only to "doctors" in the designer.

Comment: I added the setting in the main question. The extra profile.doctor page is only editable to doctors, but If the edit page shows only part of the profile page (in this case only the quote field) the other fields (email, name) are deleted
thankd for your help!

Comment: at the end the additional profile page of the doctors should be publicly availible

Comment: did you try to change your query to `findOne=false`?

Comment: I think this is not the problem. I tried and it stays the same.
there must be a better way of adding an extra part to the profile which is not updated with every field of the profile at the same time. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It does not seems to be a regular behavior. How do you remove the fields that you don't want to update? Manually or you make it in the collection field settings, using the designer?

Comment: I added an extra field to the edit function of the doctors with the designer. The query I added in the json file as I saw on the other edit examples.

Comment: I realized that I made a mistake: I copied a existing query for the doctor part from the settings. So the same query and publication was requested. That is why the data was deleted. With the designer it is not possible to add a query of the user collection, there is no value in the dropdown for that. And if I add a query manualy it is not working because there is no subscription that is fitting to the new name.

Comment: Thanks for your answert. I am bit hesitant with the fact that doctors could change everything, which means they could also change their role to admin via the console?

Comment: Indeed. If you want to avoid that, you will need to create a server method and call it on submit. The server file modifications would then not be the same. This is feasible but probably another question too.

Comment: I updated the code so that the doctor roles can only change fields different from "roles", so they can't change their roles to admin. Can you pls validate the answer if you consider this solved?